# Change OpenSSH & OpenSSL versions in Git Bash (msysgit) on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, openssh, git-bash

The versions of OpenSSH & OpenSSL in Git Bash are really old. As of this posting, when inputting `ssh -V` the versions are:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
```

My question is, how do we upgrade these (safely, without breaking anything, etc.)? [This article](http://darrell.mozingo.net/2011/09/29/painfully-slow-clone-speeds-with-msysgit-gitextensions/) has a solution, but it only mentions upgrading OpenSSH, not OpenSSL, although I'm sure you could find OpenSSL files to transfer as well. However, it requires installing Cygwin, which may not be wanted. There is a way to download the Cygwin modules but not install them, though, but this does not seem to add some DLL's like cygcrypto.dll & cygwin1.dll.

Even if this works, is there another way? Can you just download some files from openssh.com/openssl.org and change a couple config files?

Comment: My cygwin returns on `ssh -V` : OpenSSH_6.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Yes, Cygwin is apparently more up-to-date. My question was about Git Bash.

Comment: Yeah you're probably vulnerable to reverse Heartbleed and whatever else has been fixed in the last seven years.

Comment: Heartbleed is new, so if anything Git Bash probably *isn't* vulnerable to it. It is vulnerable to the Bash bug, though, not that anyone's probably going to put in the effort to make an exploit for it. I don't know about "reverse Heartbleed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
This is the file list i am using at the moment to make cygwin ssh work with git bash.

From the cygwin installation directory, copy the below filelist to your git bash 
installation directory.

Be aware, if you have configured ~/.ssh/config then you need to set correct permissions from cygwin for ssh to work properly.

cygasn1-8.dll
cygattr-1.dll
cygbz2-1.dll
cygcom_err-2.dll
cygcrypt-0.dll
cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll
cygedit-0.dll
cygform-10.dll
cygformw-10.dll
cyggcc_s-1.dll
cyggmp-10.dll
cyggmp-3.dll
cyggssapi-3.dll
cygheimbase-1.dll
cygheimntlm-0.dll
cyghistory7.dll
cyghx509-5.dll
cygiconv-2.dll
cygintl-8.dll
cygkafs-0.dll
cygkrb5-26.dll
cyglsa.dll
cyglsa64.dll
cyglua-5.1.dll
cyglzma-5.dll
cygmagic-1.dll
cygmenu-10.dll
cygmenuw-10.dll
cygmp-3.dll
cygmpfr-4.dll
cygncurses++-10.dll
cygncurses++w-10.dll
cygncurses-10.dll
cygncursesw-10.dll
cygpanel-10.dll
cygpanelw-10.dll
cygpcre-0.dll
cygpcre-1.dll
cygpopt-0.dll
cygreadline7.dll
cygroken-18.dll
cygsqlite3-0.dll
cygssl-1.0.0.dll
cygssp-0.dll
cygstdc++-6.dll
cygtic-10.dll
cygticw-10.dll
cygwin1.dll
cygwind-0.dll
cygwrap-0.dll
cygz.dll
ssh-add.exe
ssh-agent.exe
ssh-copy-id
ssh-host-config
ssh-keygen.exe
ssh-keyscan.exe
ssh-user-config
ssh.exe
sshfiles

Comment: Thank you! I don't have the patience or energy to test this now, but from what I remember when trying to do it last, Git Bash kept complaining about other files that didn't exist (in its repository; they existed to Cygwin). This was why I'm asking this question, because it seems you need to transfer more files than that blog post mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Note: the last [Git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (the [Git 2.12.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.12.1.windows.1), March 2017) uses now a much more recent OpenSSL version.
The Windows port uses now OpenSSL's implementation of SHA-1 routines

See [commit 2cfc70f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cfc70f0de7c8902791d3b23a92d6462b9e11d72) (09 Feb 2017) by [Jeff Hostetler (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 033328a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/033328a5dc22c1f52292b1941f000f0d47192ade), 13 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `mingw`: use OpenSSL's SHA-1 routines
>
> Use OpenSSL's SHA-1 routines rather than builtin block-sha1 routines.
>   This improves performance on SHA1 operations on Intel processors.
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2 has made considerable performance improvements and
>   support the Intel hardware acceleration features.

```
C:\tools\gits\latest\usr\bin>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

> See:
>
> - [(Intel) Improving OpenSSL Performance](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/improving-openssl-performance)
> - [Intel® SHA Extensions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sha-extensions)

And yes, OpenSSH is more recent too:

```
C:\tools\gits\latest\usr\bin>ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

Comment: Thanks. By this point, I've kind of accepted that Git Bash doesn't have a recent version of these 2, and when I use it (at work to connect to our Linux server, at home I have a Linux) I just use it & move on. It's good if they've updated, though.

Comment: @trysis "By this point, I've kind of accepted that Git Bash doesn't have a recent version of these 2": it actually has, since Git 2.5+ (Aug. 2015, where the maintainer was hired by Microsoft: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40059664/6309). The latest Git for Windows has *very* recent versions.

Comment: Oh, I guess I haven't kept very up-to-date. I just recently had my company's Windows maintainer person update my Git Bash for the first time in a year or 2.