# Where is Visual Studio's git.exe location?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-config

I'm configuring **git** through command line but changes seems doesn't apply to **Visual Studio**'s git actions, so I'm wondering perhaps VS uses another git instance with other configs, where can I find which git.exe is getting used by VS?

Comment: You have added git to the PATH environment variable? If you just made this change, did you restart Visual Studio?

Comment: Sure git location is added to PATH, VS has been restarted, basically with command line I set **git config core.autocrlf false** but when committing with Visual Studio it still continues editing line endings

Comment: Please tell your VS version and how you proceeded to install git beforehand. It might be helpful.

Comment: `git config core.autocrlf false` should configure the repository you executed that command in, did you use Visual Studio in that repository, or did you use it in a different one?

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio by itself manages line endings in some cases. This may not be a git issue at all.

Comment: I configure core.autocrlf both globally and locally for the repo and use visual studio in target repository. Basically what I need is path to git.exe which Visual Studio is using for performing operations with git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Git Source Control without Git for Windows or Github extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058906/visual-studio-git-source-control-without-git-for-windows-or-github-extension)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Visual Studio gets the location of the various `git` tools from the `config` file in the `.git` folder, for example, in lines like this:

```
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
    keepBackup = false
```

Other than that, the only place I can find a `git.exe` on my PC is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\git.exe
```

For Visual Studio 2022 (which runs in native 64 bit mode), the location is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
```

Comment: More info can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058906/visual-studio-git-source-control-without-git-for-windows-or-github-extension

Answer (score 13):

VS2019 appears to have a near full-blown install of Git for Windows hidden within it's installation. The only thing that appears to be stripped out of it is Mintty. So you can set the `GIT_PATH` env var as well as `GIT_SSH` just like in Git for Windows and use it via CLI as easily as using git in Visual Studio.

You can find the path here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd`

and here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin`

Set your path to the first one (this is what Git for Windows uses).

Comment: In my VS 2022 the path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd`

Comment: VS 2022 Preview:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the path are variable depending on your OS version and version of VS.

C:\{Program Files or Program Files (x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\{VS Version Year - 2017 - 2019 - 2022 - etc.\{VS Category - Community - Professional - Enterprise - etc.}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd

For example, my path is...

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 stores default git configuration data in the

```
C:\Users\<user>\.gitconfig
```

file that can be overridden in each Project's

```
...\.git\config
```

file.
For example, to get my alternative diff tool working after upgrading to VS 2022 I needed to do the following:

Execute the "git config" commands from the Visual Studio 2022 Command-Line tool:

```
git config --global diff.tool ExamDiffPro
git config --global difftool.ExamDiffPro.path "C:/Program Files/ExamDiff Pro/ExamDiff.exe"
```

This added the following lines to the

```
C:\Users\<user>\.gitconfig
```

file:

```
[diff]
    tool = ExamDiffPro
[difftool "ExamDiffPro"]
    cmd = "'C:/Program Files/ExamDiff Pro/ExamDiff.exe'" -e "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Remove any overriding [diff] settings from the local Project's

```
...\.git\config
```

file.
For example, remove:

```
[diff]
    tool = <some other tool or the default Visual Studio tool>
```