# Having multiple git.exe on Windows? Is it normal?

Tags: windows, git

I noticed that I have multiple ***git.exe*** in my computer which I didn't explicitly installed. Some seems to be installed by Visual Studio 2019/2022.

Two versions found: 2.34.1 and 2.38.1. Is this normal or have I messed up anything? I would like to have a single Git version globally setup where other apps can use. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using git via visual studios team explorer, git version control provider? If so, make sure to look at the settings within visual studio. If you are using something like [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) (which I recommend) or the command line, then those ones in visual studio don't matter.

Comment: Yes I mainly use VisualStudio so I guess it's using the git.exe installed by VS setup. So is it ok to assume to leave these as is and what if i install Git For Windows and set it to my path. Will it clash with VS git? I would like to use just one version of git in the system....

Comment: Visual studio does not seem to support picking a specific install of git, so it will always use its own. Generally though the location of git.exe is not relevant, because your [user]/.config/git folder is shared.

Comment: There is generally no issue with your situation. If you end up needing LFS (large files extension) or something non-standard, that could be an issue, and generally i don't trust visual studios git integration, but having multiple git.exe's is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it ok to assume to leave these as is and what if i install Git For Windows and set it to my path. Will it clash with VS git?

No, it will not clash: Visual Studio has Git tooling built directly into the IDE, starting with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8. It will use it directly, [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736597/6309).

You can install a regular [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) at the same time without issue.